# How to change the default Java and Python version on Ubuntu

Tags: java, python, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 18 and have
multiple versions of java and python installed, How do I change my default version.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to list the available options

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

it will ask to choose from the available versions

just enter the selection number and bingo your default java version is changed.

but the same might not work for python

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

might give an error *no alternatives for python*

To change default python to python3

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 10
```

10 here represents the weight, you can give any number of your choice